# Accessing / Parsing SOAP Messages (using JQuery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, soap

In the example given in the [jQuery.parseXML()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseXML/) documentation, if the simple XML given

```
var xml = "<rss version='2.0'><channel><title>RSS Title</title></channel></rss>"
```

is replaced by a SOAP snippet, like the one below

```
var xml = "<xyz:ServiceName>GetDetails</xyz:ServiceName>"
```

I get an invalid XML error or an Invalid/Unexpected Token error.

What should be the procedure to access the value inside 
 `<xyz:ServiceName>` tag?

Answer (score 1):

`jQuery.parseXML()` creates an XML document. You will get invalid XML here because you are using a *namespace* `xyz` which is *not* defined.

So you can define a *root* element with a *namespace* definition (any url will do) and it works fine now - see demo below:

```js
var xml = `<root xmlns:xyz="http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/">
<xyz:ServiceName>GetDetails</xyz:ServiceName>
</root>`;
console.log(jQuery(jQuery.parseXML(xml))
  .find('root').html());
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But for snippets, you can do `$(xml)`:

```js
var xml = `<xyz:ServiceName>GetDetails</xyz:ServiceName>`;
console.log($(xml).prop('outerHTML'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper{top:0;max-height:100%!important}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked very well for the code snippets! :)